# cannot display gridview inside listview in my flutter demo app

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm converting my native android project in to flutter application, in this i need to display grid of options below other widgets.

here is code

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Column homeThumb(String icon, String label) {
      Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

      return new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new Image.asset(icon, width: 32.0, height: 32.0),
          ),
          new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: new Text(
              label,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    Widget homeIcon = new Container(
        child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 40.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  homeThumb("images/icons/list.png", 'Claim Offers'),
                  homeThumb("images/icons/wallet.png", 'Wallet'),
                  homeThumb("images/icons/cart.png", 'Redeem Offers'),
                ],
              )),
          new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  homeThumb("images/icons/user.png", 'Account'),
                  homeThumb("images/icons/badge.png", 'Merchants'),
                  homeThumb("images/icons/history.png", 'Shopping History'),
                ],
              )),
          new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  homeThumb("images/icons/bell.png", 'Notifications'),
                  homeThumb("images/icons/plane.png", 'Service Request'),
                  homeThumb("images/icons/share.png", 'Share & Earn'),
                ],
              )),


        ]));

    Widget grid = new GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      children: new List<Widget>.generate(16, (index) {
        return new GridTile(
          child: new Card(
              color: Colors.blue.shade200,
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text('tile $index'),
              )
          ),
        );
      }),
    );

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Minkville',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Minkville'),
        ),
        body: new ListView(
          children: [
            new Image.asset(
              'images/slider/img_s1.jpg',
              width: 600.0,
              height: 180.0,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
            homeIcon,
            grid

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

on debug, following logs are coming

I/flutter (16594): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 441 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (16594): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#199e9 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT

Comment: Take a look over here at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095763/flutter-listview-in-a-simpledialog

Answer (score 7):

Ignore all the above answers.
Make sure you set `shrinkWrap : true` in both `ListView` and `GridView`.
Problem Solved!!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. There are a lot of widgets that automatically stretch in height, and the ability to shrinkWrap isn't always explicit. So good to know it exists for GridView

Answer (score 1):

My simplest example no CustomScrollView no SilverGrid just a normal ListView and GridView.
Heres Why I think you cant directly put a gridView inside a ListView because once you do that

- you cant differentiate whether you are scrolling a list or a grid because both are scrollable.
- ListView takes a widget and since it is scrollable it must require widgets of a defined height

so the work around here is to give it a widget of a specific height so if you give it a container of a specific height and add a grid view inside a container then this should do your job

```
List<MaterialColor> gridColors = [
  Colors.red,
  Colors.deepPurple,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.deepOrange,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.deepPurple,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.deepOrange,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.deepPurple,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.deepOrange
];



  static Widget body() {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 400,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 400,
          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate:
                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              itemCount: 8,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int x) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: gridColors[x],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 400,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

heres the output hope it helps someone

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `GridView` into an `Expanded` widget. More about that [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

Comment: Could you create an example?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Identify Problem

```dart
new ListView(
  children: [
    new Image.asset(
      'images/slider/img_s1.jpg',
      width: 600.0,
      height: 180.0,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    homeIcon,
    grid // this is the problem
  ],
),
```

the problem is here. because the grid is defined as GridView Widget, Flutter cannot
renders it as children of ListView.

```dart
Widget grid = GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
...
```

#### 2. But I want the screen to be scrollable as well?

To do that, we need to replace SingleChildScrollView or similar widget, e.g ListView. **We change it into CustomScrollView**.

This is necessary because actually, Flutter recognizes two patterns :

- List View pattern
  children will be added in the vertical direction
- Grid Box pattern
  children will be added in the Z direction. If it has two-column, its 1st and 2nd children will be rendered on First Row. then its second-row rendered with 3rd and 4th.

**Official Docs**

[image: CustomScroll]

#### 3. How to write that section?

```dart
body: CustomScrollView( // replacement of SingleScrollChildView
  slivers: <Widget>[ // rather than children, it is named slivers
    // List Pattern section
    SliverList( // replacement of ListView
      delegate : // rather than children, it is named delegate
      ...
    ),
    // Grid Pattern section
    SliverGrid(
      delegate : // rather than children, it is named delegate
      ...
    ),

  ],
)
```

#### 4. Final Code

- Changed `ListView` to `SliverList` to make a **List Section**
- Wrap it with `CustomScrollView`
- Put `SliverGrid` below `SliverList`, which is our **Grid Section**
- Render our **grid** variable, inside SliverGrid

```dart
body: new ListView( // replace this to SliverList
  children: [
    new Image.asset(
      'images/slider/img_s1.jpg',
      width: 600.0,
      height: 180.0,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    homeIcon,
    grid // needs to be moved into our Grid Section 

  ],
),
```

```dart
body: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    // A. This is our List Section
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        Image.asset(
          'images/slider/img_s1.jpg',
          width: 600.0,
          height: 180.0,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        homeIcon,
        // grid
      ]),
    ),
    // B. This is our Grid Section
    SliverGrid.count(
      children: <Widget>[grid],
      crossAxisCount: 1,
    ),
  ],
),
```

#### Demo

[image: Demo]

You may bundle it yourself by using this repo [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/a_screen/grid_view_delta.dart)