# Flutter selection dialog - scroll filter field into view

Tags: listview, flutter, scroll, keyboard

I'm trying to build a flutter selection dialog.

The dialog should show a scrollable list.
At the base of the dialog is the a text field used to filter the list.

I have this all working just fine.

The problem is that when you click on the filters text field the keyboard is displayed but it covers the text field.

I've looked at SingleChildScrollView but of course this doesn't work with a listview.

How do I solve this?

The layout is:

```
Dialog
 -> Heading
 -> SingleChildListView
     -> Column
        -> Expanded flex: 1
           -> ListView
        -> Text Field (for filter).
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your textfield is on bottom of ListView. Without detail of your code, I use flutter_typeahead to simulate your search filter action

Wrap your Column with Container and set proper height, In my demo height is 70 , you can test with your case 
Similar answer [Flutter: ListView in a SimpleDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095763/flutter-listview-in-a-simpledialog) also suggest to Wrap with Container

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    _showDialog();
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void _showDialog() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: Container(
            height: 70,
            child: TypeAheadField(
              getImmediateSuggestions: true,
              textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                autofocus: true,
                /*style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context)
                    .style
                    .copyWith(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),*/
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'What are you looking for?'),
              ),
              suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                return await BackendService.getSuggestions(pattern);
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                  title: Text(suggestion['name']),
                  subtitle: Text('\$${suggestion['price']}'),
                );
              },
              onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
               /* Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ProductPage(product: suggestion)));*/
              },
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );


  }
}



class BackendService {
  static Future<List> getSuggestions(String query) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    return List.generate(3, (index) {
      return {'name': query + index.toString(), 'price': Random().nextInt(100)};
    });
  }
}

class CitiesService {
  static final List<String> cities = [
    'Beirut',
    'Damascus',
    'San Fransisco',
    'Rome',
    'Los Angeles',
    'Madrid',
    'Bali',
    'Barcelona',
    'Paris',
    'Bucharest',
    'New York City',
    'Philadelphia',
    'Sydney',
  ];

  static List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    List<String> matches = List();
    matches.addAll(cities);

    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
  }
}
```

Demo , You can see search and scroll work correctly.

[image]

Comment: The issue is that I was trying to avoid making the listview a fixed size. I guess I could make it a percentage of the screen height but this is not my ideal solution.